# How to find the difference in minutes between two unix time in swift?

Tags: swift, swift4, nsdate

I need to find the difference between two `Unix epoch time`.

```
let currentTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
let comingFromTheServer = TimeInterval(1552078800000)
```

How to find the difference in minutes between two time? Both are `Epoch time` in local time zones

## Edit

```
let currentTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970  // printing 25842307795.623497 which is somewhere in january
let startedTinme = TimeInterval(1552090800000 / 1000)

print((currentTime - startedTinme) / 60) 

let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]
formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
let formatted = formatter.string(for: currentTime - startedTinme)
print(formatted)
```

## Edit 2

I guess there is some miscommunication happened. I want to find out the difference between `current time` vs `specific` time. I tried (updated) version of the code:

I am using this extension to get the current time in milliseconds (Epoch time)

```
extension Date {
var millisecondsSince1970:Int {
    return Int((self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0).rounded())
}

init(milliseconds:Int) {
    self = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(milliseconds) / 1000)
}
}
```

I am receiving the time from the server i.e. `1552086180000` which is `5:03 PM`

My current time is `5:12 PM`. So the difference should be `9 Minutes`. To do so, I am using

```
let currentTime = Date().millisecondsSince1970
let startedTinme = TimeInterval(1552086180000) / 1000
How can I get the difference of `9` minutes here ?
```

Comment: `TimeInterval` is in seconds, therefore I would suppose something like `abs(a - b) / 60`

Comment: In this case it doesn't make a difference but if you were gonna convert that value to a Date object you should first convert the integer to Double before dividing it by 1000 if you don't want to discard the fractional seconds.`TimeInterval(1552078800123) / 1000`

Comment: @LeoDabus I guess, You misunderstood my question. Please have a look at the Edit 2 section

Comment: @AmitPal I've just made a note about the precision loss.

Comment: @AmitPal you can simply initialise your startTime date an get the timeIntervalSinceNow. Note that the result will always be negative for past dates. If you need the elapsedTime just use `Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime)` and divide the resulting number of seconds by 60 to find out the difference in minutes.

Comment: `extension Date {
    var millisecondsSince1970: Int {
        return Int(timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    }
    init(millisecondsSince1970: Int) {
        self.init(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(millisecondsSince1970)/1000)
    }
}
let serverTime = Date(millisecondsSince1970: 1552086180000)
let elapsedMinutes = Date().timeIntervalSince(serverTime) / 60`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to convert the time coming from server to `TimeInterval` correctly. Unix time is usually in milliseconds while `TimeInterval` is in seconds, therefore:

```
let currentTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
let comingFromTheServer = TimeInterval(1552078800000) / 1000
```

Then just calculate difference and convert to minutes:

```
print((currentTime - comingFromTheServer) / 60) // 160
```

or formatted:

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]
formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
let formatted = formatter.string(from: currentTime - comingFromTheServer) ?? ""
print(formatted) // 160m 41s
```

Considering your `millisecondsSince1970` function, just convert it back to seconds:

```
let currentTime = TimeInterval(Date().millisecondsSince1970) / 1000
let startedTime = TimeInterval(1552086180000) / 1000
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should I cast comingFromTheServer to Int? because both are different data type

Comment: @AmitPal You are already "casting" to `TimeInterval`, you probably don't need anything else.

Comment: @sulthsn It's throwing an casting compilation error at `print((currentTime - comingFromTheServer) / 60) // 160` . Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'TimeInterval' (aka 'Double). Please check the #Edit section in question

Comment: You are now using some method `Date.millisecondsSince1970` which is unknown to me and then trying to compare with `TimeInterval` which is *in seconds*. Either use `Int` for both or `TimeInterval` for both. Don't mix them.

Comment: Thanks for the update but `Date().timeIntervalSince1970` is not giving the correct  time (current)

Comment: I have updated the #EDIT section with the updated code